# One touch moving in 2 points, but it is not moving

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

Please help!
I want to let my ball moving when the screen is touched to other position and on next touch to original position. 
I only want to change X position the Y will be the same.
But when I touch the screen it is doing nothing.
This is the code, I have written for the ball.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    addball()
}
func addball() {
    ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ball")
    self.ball.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/4, frame.size.height/3)
    self.addChild(ball)
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    if touches.count % 2 == 0 {
        let right = SKAction.moveToX(frame.size.width/4*3, duration: 0.1)
        self.ball.runAction(right)
    } else {
        let left = SKAction.moveToX(frame.size.width/4, duration: 0.1)
        self.ball.runAction(left)
    }
    }
}
```

Thanks for all answers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a silly answer, but are you touching it with 2 fingers at the same time?

Try doing touches.count > 0 instead to test if it is just the touch.

If you are touching 1 finger, then another,  your touch count will stay at 1 because only 1 touch began event happened.

The first touch will be part of the move state, the second touch is your begin state

Edit:

```
var toggle = false;
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        if toggle {
            let right = SKAction.moveToX(frame.size.width/4*3, duration: 0.1)
            self.ball.runAction(right)
        } else {
            let left = SKAction.moveToX(frame.size.width/4, duration: 0.1)
            self.ball.runAction(left)
        }
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is going to the right side of the screen but on the second touch it isn't going back.

Comment: you need to redo your touch logic it seems, perhaps set yourself up a toggle boolean `code`
var toggle = false;
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    if toggle {
        let right = SKAction.moveToX(frame.size.width/4*3, duration: 0.1)
        self.ball.runAction(right)
    } else {
        let left = SKAction.moveToX(frame.size.width/4, duration: 0.1)
        self.ball.runAction(left)
    }

    }
toggle = !toggle;
}`code`

Comment: Thank you very much it's going well